# Data from the observable is always undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service which return observables of an object array

```
allFruits: Fruit[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "fruit 1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "fruit 2"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "fruit 3"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "fruit 4"
    }
  ];
```

```
function getFruits {
 return of(allFruits);
}
```

Component

```
allFruits: Observable<Fruit[]>;
constructor(
    private fruitService: FruitService
  ) {
    this.fruitService
       .getFruits()
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(() => {
        results => this.allFruits == results;
      });
```

this.allFruits is always undefined and it does not have any values in there. If I do console.log(results) I do get the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want `allFruits` to be an array rather than an Observable. Is that correct? I also changed the subscribe lambda function a little.

```js
allFruits: Fruit[];
constructor(
    private fruitService: FruitService
  ) {
    this.fruitService
       .getFruits()
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(results => {
        this.allFruits == results;
      });
```

If your intent is to use this service in conjunction with the `async` pipe, you could do something like the following:

```js
allFruits: Observable<Fruit[]>;
constructor(
    private fruitService: FruitService
  ) {
    this.allFruits = this.fruitService
       .getFruits()
       .pipe(first());
```

You can then use `allFruits` with the async pipe in your template.

Comment: Yes, Is it a good practice to assign results is observable of fruit to an array which is not an observable?

Comment: The data in the `result` variable you receive in the subscribe function is not an observable. You actually get back an Array of Fruit there.

Comment: So in the HTML do we check for the length of allFruits before showing the html?
Like ngIf =" allFruits?.Length > 0. Is that how it supposed to be? What about using async pipe then

Comment: You can use the length like that sure. To use the async pipe you need an Observable. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Francus.. Thank you but what is the best possible way to do this? and industry standard?

Comment: If your Observable completes immediately after the first value it emits (or if you user the 'first' operator) I'd say either way is fine. But if your observable doesn't complete and can potentially emit more values, the async pipe is a nice way to hook that up in your template because it will automatically do an unsubscribe for you when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks alot! So if the observable emits more values do we have to subscribe after the first() as well like .pipe(first()).subscribe?

Comment: No. If you use the async pipe, you don't need to subscribe. You pass the observable to the async pipe and it will subscribe for you..

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry but last question. If I do not use pipe and use subscribe -   this.getAllFruits.subscribe(results => {
        this.allFruits == results); 
Does this line means that it is not returning observable and I can just put all the results in an array?

Comment: `this.fruitService,getFruits()` returns an observable. `this.fruitService,getFruits().subscribe(results => { this.allFruits == results)` returns a Subscription object. This subscription will update the `this.allFruits` variable with an array of fruit every time the `getFruits` observable emits a value. Of course, the `getFruits`  observable in your question will only emit once and complete right after.

The direct answer to your question is that isn't returning an observable. And the `this.allFruits` variable will contain the array of fruits.

Comment: Thanks again but what if getFruits observable emits multiple times, what is the best way then? We cannot use first() because we need all the emitted items

Comment: The `getFruits` observable in the service in your question will emit an array of fruits only once. But if it were to be redesigned to potentially emit new arrays over time, the subscription created with `this.fruitService,getFruits().subscribe(results => { this.allFruits == results)` will ensure that the `this.allFruits` variable will always contain the latest emitted value.

Answer (score 2):

You must not use equality operater `==` instead of `=` assignment operator.

```
allFruits: Observable<Fruit[]>;
constructor(
    private fruitService: FruitService
  ) {
    this.fruitService
       .getFruits()
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(() => {
        results => this.allFruits = results;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allFruits: Observable<Fruit[]>;
constructor(
    private fruitService: FruitService
  ) {
    this.fruitService
       .getFruits()
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(() => {
        results => this.allFruits = results;
      });
```

But here first() operator will return first obj which is not of type Array either you should not use Array type or you should remove first() pipe